# How can I change the profile for running an integration test?

Tags: quarkus

I'm executing a test using `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`. Obviously, this is run with the `prod` profile, not the `test` profile.

How can I activate the `test` profile in a simple way for my integration test? Right now, I'm forced to create a separate `QuarkusTestProfile` and annotate it with `@TestProfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use the `quarkus.test.native-image-profile=test` property

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! But it's a bit confusing to have "native image" in there, since I'm not testing with a native image.

Comment: Yeah, I need to fix that :)

Answer (score 0):

By now, there is a dedicated configuration key:

`quarkus.test.integration-test-profile`

https://quarkus.io/guides/continuous-testing#quarkus-test-dev-testing-test-config_quarkus.test.native-image-profile